# Парсинг сложного json файла

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

[image: json]

[json файл](https://uploadfiles.io/cec31)
  Помогите распарсить данный `json`. Конкретно нужно доступ к ключам `controlworks`, `courseprojects` и тд. Не могу понять до конца структуру. Прошу обратить внимание на то, что массивы 2013-2014, 2014-2015 и тд. не статичны. Т.е с сервера их может прийти либо 4 или 1 и тд. Ниже код, с которым я смог лишь динамически выводить название массивов '2013-2014' и тд.

```
var rnpFilters = JSON.parse(rnpFiltersString);
$.each( rnpFilters.rnp, function(key, val) {
    console.log(key); // 2013-2014, 2014-2015, 2015-2016
});
```

Comment: можно было бы и сам json прикрепить...... а кто такие идиотские ключи генерирует? вроде внутри этого цикла можно сделать еще один цикл по ключам `for (i.........i < rnpFilters.rnp[key].length....`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский ну идиотские не идиосткие не ваше дело. такие от бэка приходят.

Comment: ммм..значит вы.. ясно xD  ........лучше для динамических годов в качестве ключей  сделайте статичное название. Про цикл надеюсь видели сообщение-то

Comment: @Алексей Шимански нет, не я. какая разница. мне их записать в таблицу циклов да и все. мне все равно какие имена ключей

Comment: @Алексей Шимански , не могу. 
Название годов используються как текст-навазние табов.
`$.each( rnpFilters.rnp, function(key, val) {  
         nextTab = $('#tabs li').length + 1;  
         //create the tab  
         $('<li><a href="#tab'+nextTab+'" data-toggle="tab">'+key+'</a></li>').appendTo('#tabs');  
         
     });`

Comment: что вы не можете? не понял...я вам не предлагал захардкодить что-то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если необходимо вытащить только `controlworks`

```
var rnpFilters = JSON.parse(rnpFiltersString);
$.each( rnpFilters.rnp, function(key, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        console.log(val[i].controlworks);
    }
});
```

Если необходимо вытащить все подряд

```
var rnpFilters = JSON.parse(rnpFiltersString);
    $.each( rnpFilters.rnp, function(key, val) {
        for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            for (item in val[i]) {
                console.log(key + ' ' + item + ' ' + val[i][item]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: [Скрин](http://imgur.com/zO83Mu7)
Результат не тот что ожидался) Необходимо вывести все поля со всех объектов массивов ('2013-2014 и тд)

Comment: @MishaKagarlykskiy обновил ответ

Comment: Действительно все. Нужно было лишь конечные значения полей. Думаю дальше разберусь. Спасибо

Comment: @MishaKagarlykskiy "Спасибо" на SO это принятый ответ или/и голос за.

Comment: @MishaKagarlykskiy что самое смешное, решение в виде пробега `for (i.........i < rnpFilters.rnp[key].length....` я написал еще в самом первом своем  комментарии, (где `rnpFilters.rnp[key].length` в принципе есть `val.length`) но вы чудесным образом решили не обращать внимание на это и начать обиженный разговор про ключи.... хоспаде.... куда катится мир